# Proving an infinite number of primes of the form 6n+1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

The proofs given on other sites weren't that clear and used different methods that I have yet to learn.

---

**Prove that there are an infinite number of primes of the form 6n+1.**

*The **hint** that was given was:
Let p = p1, p2, ..., pk + 1, where p1 = 2, p2 = 3,...pk are the first k primes.  Show that p is prime.*

(p1 means p sub 1, p2 means p sub 2, and pk is p sub k.  Wasn't sure how to write it on this.)

---

Can someone explain this hint on how they came about of p1 = 2, p2=3, etc, and prove this please?

Also, how would the proof change if the form changed?  ("Prove that there are infinite number of primes of the form....")

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the hint means a product of primes plus $1$, it is wrong: if you take the first $6$ primes you get $2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13+1=30031$, which is $59\times509$.

Comment: I noticed that as well, but wasn't sure if they continued taking primes.  How would I prove this if I didn't use the hint?

Comment: Are you sure it is not $6n-1$. The hint is often used to prove for $6n-1$. I can provide a simple proof for that, if you want. Not sure how to use the hint for $6n+1$

Comment: There is a result (Dirichlet's Theorem) which says that there are always infinitely many primes of the form $an+b$, as long as $a$ and $b$ have no common factor.  However this is a very difficult result and I doubt it's what you're looking for.  There are simple proofs for certain cases, such as $4n-1$ and $6n-1$, and $4n+1$ is a bit harder but not too hard.

Comment: I added a picture of what I am looking at.  However, how would the proof look like if it were 6n-1?  Maybe I can get an idea if I looked at it.

Comment: See my answer below for $6n-1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint is clearly false. Let me answer a question that was **not** asked as it used the hint that is provided. I realize that this does not help OP but hopefully it will help the OP in some other problem.

**Show that there are infinitely many primes of the form $6n-1$**

Suppose not. Let there be only finitely many primes of the form $6n-1$, say $p_1$, $p_2$ $\cdots$, $p_k$. Let
$$
P = 6 p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k - 1
$$
Now every prime is either of the form $6n-1$ or $6n+1$ and product of any two numbers of the form $6n+1$ is also of the form $6n+1$. So the question is

**What are the prime dividers of $P$?**

They *all* can't be of the form $6n+1$ since $P$ is of the form $6n -1$. So it must have at least one prime factor of the form $6n-1$. Clearly $p$ is not divisible by any of the primes $p_1$, $p_2$, $\cdots$ $p_k$. So there has to be a prime of the form $6n-1$ which is different from these primes. Hence, there has to be infinitely many primes of the form $6n-1$.

*I fully realize that this does not answer OP's question* but the method and the hint is similar. Hope this helps

Comment: Very helpful thank you.  I have one more question.  If I had a whole new question to where the form changed, to say what David mentioned about to 4n-1, would the proof be similar to this?

Comment: Same logic. Product of two numbers of the form $4n+1$ is also of the same form. So, consider $P=4 p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k - 1$. Now $P$ must have a factor of the form $4n-1$ that is different than $p_1$, $p_2$ ... $p_k$.

Comment: Sounds great.  Quick question I just thought about.  What if I had the form of other than +/- 1?  Say, 6n+5?  Would the proof be for P= 6p_1 p_2...p_k+5?

Comment: 6n+5 is same as 6n-1. The key is that numbers of the form $4n+1$ and $6n+1$ are **closed** under multiplication, so if you from a number that is not in that form, that number must have a factor not in that form. $4$ and $6$ are nice because $\phi(4)=\phi(6)=2$, so every number greater than $4$ or $6$ that is not of the form $4n\pm1$ and $6n\pm1$ is a composite number.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see.  Many thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

Make a list of (supposedly) all the primes, then write the product
$$  Q = p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k, $$
and write
$$  N = 12 Q^2 + 1. $$

You need to know how to prove this much: if we have a prime $q \equiv 5 \pmod 6,$ and
$$ 3 u^2 + v^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q, $$ then both
$$  u,v  \equiv 0 \pmod q. $$

Proved the general fact at
[Prime divisors of $k^2+(k+1)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291070/prime-divisors-of-k2k12/2291224#2291224)

Comment: I know this is a long time after, but could you explain how to prove that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct conclusion of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions.

Or you can prove it directly, but it takes more work. Here's a proof from [MATHBLAG](https://mathblag.wordpress.com/2013/08/30/primes-of-the-form-6k1/):

Let P be a finite set of primes of the form $6k + 1$, and let N be a number that is divisible by every number in P. Assume that N is also divisible by 6. Let p be a prime divisor of $N^2-N+1$.

Note that $(N^2-N+1)(N+1)=N^3+1$. so p divides $N^3+1$, or in other words $N^3 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ and so $N^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Recall that the order of N modulo p is the least positive k so that $N^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. The order must divide 6. so k = 1, 2, 3, or 6. But $N^3 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, so the order cannot be 1 or 3.

Can the order be 2? If $N^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $N^3 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ then $N \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. This would be bad, because then p would divide both $N+1$ and $N^2-N+1$; but $\gcd(N+1,N^2-N+1) = \gcd(N+1,3) < p$, contradiction.

Thus N has order 6 mod p, and the group of units mod p has order $p-1$, so 6 divides $p-1$, which means that p has the form $6k+1$. Therefore, P does not contain all primes of the form $6k+1$, so the set of primes of this form is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

let there are finite number primes in the form $6n-1$
Let they all are $S=\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5.....p_n\}$.
Let a number $Q=6(p_1*p_2*p_3*p_4.......p_n)-1$.
Either Q is prime or composite.
If Q is prime we are done. Since Q is in form 6n-1 and not in S.(Contradiction)
If p is composite then there must be a prime let M (not in S) which is a factor of Q. We know M must be in the form 6n-1 or 6n+1.
so Q=Mq for some q. If m is in form 6n-1 then this contradicts our supposition. If M is in the form 6n+1 then our left-hand side is congruent to 5 mod6 but the right-hand side is congruent to 1 mod 6 which is not possible, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

If we cross out from sequence of positive integers all numbers divisible by $2 $ and all numbers divisible by $3$ then all remaining numbers will be in one of two forms:

$S1(n)=6n−1=5,11,17,..$ or $S2(n)=6n+1=7,13,19,....n=1,2,3,...$

So all prime numbers also will be in one of these two forms and ratio 0f number of primes in the sequence $S1(n)$ to number of primes in the sequence $S2(n)$ tends to be $1$. See link http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=13752&lngWId=3

Comment: see [link]https://www.academia.edu/13890086/Matrix_sieve_the_easiest_way_to_find_prime_numbers