# Infinitely many prime numbers 6n-1

Tags: number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $6n-1$. I proved that there are infinitely many prime numbers but I couldn't bring it in the form given in the question. While proving it, I was getting $6n+1$ not $6n-1$.

Comment: See the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671820/proving-an-infinite-number-of-primes-of-the-form-6n1).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407259/how-do-you-prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-5-6n

Comment: Oh, thanks. Didn't know the question had already been asked.