# Prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers that can't be written as $6xy+x+y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem: Prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers that can't be written as $6xy+x+y$ where $x,y$ are positive integers.

I noticed that if $A=6xy+x+y$ then $6A+1=(6x+1)(6y+1)$, but I can't proceed from here. A hint would be great!

Comment: Do natural numbers include zero?

Comment: There are infinitely many primes

Comment: @KennyLau  we spontaneously conclude.

Comment: Since $\,x,y\ge 1\,$ the factors $\,6x+1,6y+1\,$ are both greater than $1$. So if $\,A\,$ has that form then $\,6A+1\,$ is composite. So if $\,6A+1\,$ is prime then $\,A\,$ does not have that form. But there are [infinitely many primes of form $\,6A+1.\, $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671820/proving-an-infinite-number-of-primes-of-the-form-6n1) **QED** $\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Prime is infinite of form $6k+1$ where $k$ is an integer  and prime cannot be written as two product.

Comment: ...except with 1.

Comment: @kennyLau my typing is so slow so when I go to university, I will train my self lololol

Comment: Sorry...don't you need to show that there are infinitely many primes of the form $6A+1$?  That is true, of course, but considerably deeper than the infinitude of primes.

Comment: @lulu that's why my word "Hint" there. It only remind the OP of how to carry out the solution rather than give a full solution and give the OP some clue about how to prove infinitely many primes of the form 6A+1.

Comment: @ZackNi I think that "hint" is far too vague. Please give more details about the proof that you have in mind.

Comment: @BillDubuque uh, if I write, it will duplicate this post:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671820/proving-an-infinite-number-of-primes-of-the-form-6n1

Comment: @ZackNi Well at least now the OP has a link to finish the proof.

Comment: @billdubuque but I believe he had googled it.