# Prove that $4bc+3b+3c+2$ is never a perfect square

Tags: proof-writing, diophantine-equations

How can I show that for every pair of non-negative integers $(b,c)$, the expression

$$4bc + 3b + 3c + 2$$

is not a perfect square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the answer by Thomas, with some integer $x,$ $1 + x^2$ is never divisible by any (positive) prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$ The quick reason for this is that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod q.$ Writing the Legendre symbol $(-1|q) = -1.$

I wrote a short proof of the general fact at [Prime divisors of $k^2+(k+1)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291070/prime-divisors-of-k2k12/2291224#2291224)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Multiply by $4$ and you get $(4b+3)(4c+3)-1$.

If this is a square then $(4b+3)(4c+3)$ can be written as the sum of two squares.

Comment: Why would that be the case then?

Comment: Why would what even be the case? There are a lot of claims up there. Help me help you.

Comment: How do you deduce what you're saying in your last sentence?

Comment: If $(4b+3)(4c+3)-1$ is a perfect square, then $(4b+3)(4c+3)$ is one plus a perfect square.