# How to prove that there are infinitely many primes of form $6n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

We know that all primes greater than $3$ are of form $6n+1$ or $6n-1,$ but how do I prove that there are infinitely many of the form $6n+1$?  Please prove it without Dirichlet's theorem.

Note:  This question is not a duplicate of [Proving an infinite number of primes of the form 6n+1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671820/proving-an-infinite-number-of-primes-of-the-form-6n1); there people are discussing about $6n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), the arithmetic progression $$a_0=1\quad\quad a_{n}=1+6n$$
contains infinitely many primes since gcd$(1,6)=1$. Can you end it from here?