# Prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers that satisfy $ (p^2)+2p=-1 \pmod 6$,

Tags: number-theory

I have been struggling with this question. I don’t know how to proceed. Would you be able to walk me through the steps to complete it?

Comment: it seems to be false, $(p+1)^2$ is always $0$ or $1\bmod 3$

Comment: $(p^2)+2p \equiv-1 \bmod 6$ iff $(p+1)^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 6$ iff $p \equiv -1 \bmod 6$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/671854/589 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407259/how-do-you-prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-5-6n

Comment: There are [infinitely many primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) of the form $p=6k+5$.